# Odoo inheritance issue

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have develop a module for odoo 8.
When I tried to deploy it a I got this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 539, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 576, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 312, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 309, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 805, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 405, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 948, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 447, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_install, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 495, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.new(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 370, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 355, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 255, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 176, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 118, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 900, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 986, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 852, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](self.cr, rec, n, mode=mode)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 762, in _tag_record
    id = self.pool['ir.model.data']._update(cr, self.uid, rec_model, self.module, res, rec_id or False, not self.isnoupdate(data_node), noupdate=self.isnoupdate(data_node), mode=self.mode, context=rec_context )
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1065, in _update
    res_id = model_obj.create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 255, in create
    context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 372, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 4093, in create
    record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 508, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **old_kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 4284, in _create
    recs._validate_fields(vals)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 1271, in _validate_fields
    raise ValidationError('\n'.join(errors))
ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Field `note` does not exist

Error context:
View `hr.skill form`
[view_id: 1027, xml_id: n/a, model: hr.skill, parent_id: 849]" while parsing /opt/odoo/addons/nge_skills_management/skill.xml:32, near
<record id="view_skill_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="model">hr.skill</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_skill.view_skill_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='name']" position="after">
                     <field name="note" string="Note"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

But When I check my database I found the note field:

```
 select * from  nge_skills_management_hr_skill;
 id | parent_left | parent_right | create_uid | create_date | name | write_uid | note | parent_id | write_date | active 
----+-------------+--------------+------------+-------------+------+-----------+------+-----------+------------+--------
```

There are my source code:

skill.py

```
from openerp import api, fields, models
class hr_skill(models.Model):
    _inherit = "hr.skill"

    _name = "nge_skills_management.hr_skill"
    note = fields.Selection([('a', '3'),('b', '2'),('c', '1')])
```

skill.xml

```
    <menuitem id="main_skill_menu" name="Nge Skills" />

        <menuitem id="skill_menu" name="My skills"
            parent="main_skill_menu" />

        <record id="action_home_page" model="ir.actions.client">
            <field name="name">Skill Home</field>
            <field name="tag">nge_skills_management.homepage</field>
        </record>

        <menuitem id="home_page_skill_menu" name="Home Page" parent="skill_menu"
            action="action_home_page"/>

 <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="nge_skills_action">
            <field name="name">NGE Skills</field>
            <field name="res_model">hr.skill</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="domain">[["parent_id.name", "=", "Programmation"]]</field>
        </record>

             <record id="view_skill_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="model">hr.skill</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_skill.view_skill_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='name']" position="after">
                     <field name="note" string="Note"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>

<menuitem id="nge_skills_action_menu" name="NGE SKILLS" parent="skill_menu"
            action="nge_skills_action"/>
```

Can anyone help me please !!

Comment: I would suggest you to remove `_name` from file `skill.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In odoo specifying `_name` creates a new table in the database (the name of the module is the name of the database table with the `.` replaced with `_`).

The problem is you are using:

`_name = 'nge_skills_management.hr_skill'` which is going to create a new table with the fields in `hr.skill` and add a notes field to it not to the `hr_skill` module

what you want (Normal inheritance) is simply to specify `_inherit='hr.skill'` only. this will enable you add new fields or new methods to the `hr.skill` model

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @Hamdi if you found an answer useful or it resolved your problem please mark it as accepted and/or upvote it